# Fixing link_to links After Adding Custom Routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I took away a directory level from root/admin/posts/:id to root/posts/:id in my routes.rb file with this line of code:

```
get 'posts/:id' => 'admin/posts#show'
```

That works fine. However, my link_to links are still pointing to admin/posts/:id.

Here is my .erb:

```
<div class="container">
<% @admin_posts.each do |admin_post| %>
  <div class="blog-post">
    <h2><%= link_to admin_post.title, admin_post %></h2>
    <h5><%= admin_post.created_at%></h5>
    <p><%= raw(admin_post.content) %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

I am new to rails and I know this must be simple but I can't seem to figure it out. Can anyone tell me how to get my link_to pointing in the right direction?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you install any admin related gem? since `admin_post` route is still working

Comment: Thanks for your reply! No, I did not install any admin related gems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom routes do not get named automatically, you have to name them yourself. As per @nayiaw's comment though, you should make sure you are not overriding another routes name.

```
get 'posts/:id' => 'admin/posts#show', as: 'admin_post'
```